# Trying to close spinner in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to find a way to close my spinner once the action method spits out the excel spreadsheet i.e. once the button click has finished its job. I cant use Jquery AJAX to do this because my action method is returning FileContentResult.The question is, Is there a javascript event that i could hook into to close my spinner? Appreciate if you could Please point me in the right direction :) I have posted some code below

Thanks

```
@model WorkflowSLAChaser_Search_Model

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutReport.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "SLA Chaser Report";
}
<h2 id="title">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SLAChaserReport", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <br />
        <p>Change Request Report in Microsoft Excel.</p>
        <br />
        <div id="spinner-target-area">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group" style="padding:5px">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnsearch" name="searchButton" value="Download SLA Chaser Report" class="btn btn-primary btn-xxxlge" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    }
</div>

@section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {             
                $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
                    $.fn.RunSpinner();                 
                });
                }
            }); 



//$.fn.StopSpinner();
            
        </script>
}

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SLAChaserReport(WorkflowSLAChaser_Search_Model model)
        {
return new FileContentResult();
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to let us know what "Spinner" you are using. For instance, there is a spin.js, and a ton of different spinner libraries. The more information you give us the faster we can help you.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, appreciate your response. I have taken over someone code obviously so please see below (function ($) {
    $.fn.RunSpinner = function () {
        $('#overlay').addClass("show");
    };

    $.fn.StopSpinner = function () {
        $('#overlay').removeClass("show");
    };
})(jQuery);

Comment: I think its a bit of CSS you hide and show.

Comment: @keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}